# Recursively symlink directory tree

Tags: bash, macos, recursion, ln

I'm trying to run a recursive symlink from one directory into another:

```sh
find data/* -type d -exec ln -s {} current/{} \;
```

With one addition: I need to strip off `data/` from the prefix.

Running on OS X server (10.8, Mountain Lion)--not all standard GNU commands, like `cp -rs`, are supported.

What I mean by recursively:

`data` is a list of persistent directories between Laravel releases:

```
data/
    \ storage/
        - framework/
            - session/
        - app/
        \ logs/
```

They need to map to:

```
current/
    \ storage/
        - framework
            - session/
        - app/
        - logs/
      # Also in storage, but we do NOT want to persist
        - debugbar/
        - framework/
            - cache/
            - views/
```

Our `data` directory is will be persistent storage between application launches, as we update our site, while retaining previous versions of the site in the event of rollbacks (`current` happens to be a softlink to the latest release).

Note: we also have other sites other than Laravel. `data` is going to be our standard, and we're going to match directory restructure depending on what the site requires for persistence. It won't always be `data/storage`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "recursive"? Once you've created a link from `current/foo` to `data/foo` (for example), all of its subdirectories are already accessible through that link… you don't need to do anything additional.

Comment: @duskwuff - already made it obvious, don't recurse. You can simply `find data -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -s ../{} current \;`

Comment: @duskwuff: `data/foo/bar` => `current/foo/bar`, `data/foo/bartwo/play` => `current/foo/bartwo/play`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do any recursion. Once you've linked to a directory, all of the files and directories under it are accessible through the link.

The only links you need are to the directories at the top level…

```
cd current
ln -s ../data/*/ .
```

Or, depending on your requirements, making `current` a link to `data` might even be sufficient.

Comment: Wrong. You'll end up with `current` having links that points to nowhere. Try `cd current; ln -s ../data/*/ .`.

Comment: @alvits Thanks, fixed. (Or just use an absolute path to `current`.)

Comment: My apologies, I failed to mention the `data` directory is not a complete set of directories, just a subset of what's to be shared. I'll update the post.

Comment: @duskwuff Oh and I tried that. Didn't work because `current` is a softlink to `release/{revnum}/` - resulted in `../data` not found, due to the resolved pathing of softlinks.

Comment: For me it had to run two commands: 1. for making symlink for files (ln -s ../data/*.*) and 2. FOr making symlink for subdirectories (ln -s ../data/*/ .)

Answer (score 4):

GNU stow.
https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/

Try:

```
# cd to dir above ./data
mkdir datalinks
stow -d datalinks data
```

Stow will intelligently work around existing files in the source dir as well. If a dit doesn't exist it'll symlink the dir, but if it does, it'll symlink the contents.

Takes a while to get one's head around it but once you do, it opens up a new way of thinking about file/symlink mgmt.
Think about a sparsely populated tree where only new files are actual files, and everything else is a symlink to what was there before - and you have Apple's time machine. If you've ever browser a time machine backup from a shell, you'll see it's identical to an rsnapshot backup.
All based on sparse tree symlink population, of which stow is the swiss army knife.

Comment: This is safer than the accepted answer, since the question does not specify if (any parts of) the sub-directory structure @guice is trying to create already exist; I believe some suggested answers would accidentally clobber parts of that existing structure with the new one.

Comment: Agreed, `stow` is an unsung hero. Doesn't get the credit it deserves.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering about how to recursively sylink all files from one directory to another.

I needed this and couldn't find any good solutions around for `macOS`.

Following is the best solution if available:

```
cp -Rs <src_dir> <dest_dir>
```

Otherwise, what I did is:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

symlink_recursive_copy() {
    local src_dir=$1 ; shift
    local target_dir=$1
    local basename
    local cdir
    local full_path_cdir
    local full_path_target_dir
    local opwd=$PWD

    if [ -e "$target_dir" ]
    then
        >&2 echo "$target_dir already exists"
        return 1
    fi

    target_dir="$opwd/${target_dir##*/}"

    cd "$src_dir"

    while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do
        basename="${file##*/}"
        cdir="${file%/*}"
        cd "$cdir" ; full_path_cdir=$PWD ; cd "$OLDPWD"
        mkdir -p "$target_dir/$cdir"
        ln -s "$full_path_cdir/$basename" "$target_dir/$cdir/$basename"
    done < <( find . -type f -print0 )

    cd "$opwd"
}

symlink_recursive_copy "$@"
```

The above should work with any kind of files containing newlines, spaces, quotes, trailing newlines etc.